# why is my program not working in javac compiler but working in an IDE

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is a simple program that should have been done in 10 min.but this error keeps on coming telling that the javac compiler has reached end of file while parsing.But when I run the same thing in IDE(Net beans).I get the result.

```
  public class beerbottlesong
  {
 public static void main (String[] args){
 int x=99;//value given to no. of beer bottles
 while(x>0)//starting while loop
 {
  System.out.println (x + "bottles of beer on the wall" + x + " bottles of beer.");

  System.out.println ("Take one down and pass it around, " + (x-1) + " bottles of beer on the wall");
  x--;//decrementing the value of beer bottles

  }//end while loop

  }//end main method

  }//error occured in javac -reached end of file while parsing
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the files are the same? You will get that error if you're missing the trailing `}`

Comment: Commenting the end bracket is more time consuming and harder to read than just formatting it correctly.

Comment: If you are still having this problem, try going to the end of the source file and add a blank line or two, and see if that makes the problem go away.  Although this seems unlikely to solve anything, I've seen programs that have problems with text files that don't end in a proper newline character sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine from a javac compiler.

Make sure you use the commands

```
javac FileName.java

java FileName
```

Please make the class name `BeerBottleSong`, Please follow a proper naming-convention.

---

If you still can't run your program make sure you have class path set.

Answer (score 2):

When I compile this class I get

```
peter@hex:~$ javac beerbottlesong.java
peter@hex:~$ ls -l beerbottlesong.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 850 Aug 23 04:53 beerbottlesong.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 498 Aug 23 04:53 beerbottlesong.java
peter@hex:~$ java beerbottlesong 
99bottles of beer on the wall99 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall
98bottles of beer on the wall98 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 97 bottles of beer on the wall
```

Answer (score 0):

When running your code you don't change the your "bottles" to "bottle" when one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int beerNum = 99;
    String word = "bottles";
    while (beerNum > 0) {

        System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer.");
        System.out.println("Take one down.");
        System.out.println("Pass it around.");
        beerNum = beerNum - 1;
        if (beerNum == 1) {
            word = "bottle"; // singular, as in ONE bottle.
        }
        if (beerNum > 0) {
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
        }  // end else
    }// end while loop
} // end main method
```